# images in scrollview autolayout swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I put images in a `UIScrollview` programmatically. When I run a simulator on an iPhone 8, the width of each image fits perfectly to the screen. But, when I run it on iPhone 8 Plus, the width of images is shorter than that of the screen. I think there is something wrong with the auto layout. What can be a possible reason behind this?
I put the following codes in `ViewDidLoad`.

```
scrollViewData = [scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 1")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 2")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 3")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 4")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 5")), scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "promotion test 6"))]

    scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(scrollViewData.count)

    var i = 0
    for data in scrollViewData {
        let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
        view.imageView.image = data.image
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)



        i += 1
```

I put the following code separately

```
class CustomView: UIView {

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    return imageView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: share constraints code , or screenshots if in IB

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Instead of telling us “I put the codes in `ViewDidLoad`”, please **show us the codes**. Edit your question to include the code, by copying and pasting it from your project.

Comment: Thanks I have added the codes!

Answer (score 0):

The `iPhone 8` has screen dimensions of 1334x750, which is a ratio of 667:375.

The `iPhone 8 Plus` has screen dimensions of 1920×1080, which is a ratio of 16:9.

So yes, the image will not fit perfectly. So, to zoom the `UIScrollView` should hopefully work like this:

```
view.zoom(to: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height, animated: false)
```

Comment: it does not work but I have added my codes up there. could you plese have a look?

Comment: @LeeSangYun Okay. I’ll have a look in the evening

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to say what the problem might be without having seen your code, but I just noticed that you said:

> I put the codes in `ViewDidLoad`.

One problem with that might be, that at the time when `viewDidLoad` is called in the lifecycle, you can't rely on the view dimensions you see.

If you want to see this "in action" you could try adding:

`print(view.frame)`

to

- `viewDidLoad()`
- `viewWillAppear(_:)`
- `viewDidAppear(_:)`
- `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

and see that the values are changing as you progress through the life cycle.

Yeah, not really an answer, but just something you should be aware of when setting up your view hierarchy.

### Edit, after you updated your code

So you've added some code to your question, thanks :)

I stumbled over this line:

> let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))

As I wrote above, you can not be sure that the size of your `scrollView` is correct in `viewDidLoad`. Try adding the `print(scrollView.frame)` call in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` and see if the size doesn't change.

So, try moving the code where you add content to your `scrollView` to `viewWillAppear` instead maybe.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have added the codes up there. Could you please have a look?